# Why is the question assuming $r = (r_1+r_2)/2$ instead of $ r = r_1$

Tags: integration

The following is a problem from internet.
[image: Cylinder]

Volume of sphere is (when we assume  $(r_1+r_2)/2$)

$$ V = \pi  (r_2^2 - r_1^2)  h $$

$$ V = \pi  (r_2 - r_1)  (r_2 + r_1) h $$

$$ V = \pi  \hspace{1mm} \Delta r \hspace{1mm} (r_2 + r_1) h $$

$$ V = \pi  \hspace{1mm} \Delta r \hspace{1mm} 2r h $$

However, if we assume $r = r_1$ and maximum radius is $R$

$$ V = \pi  \hspace{1mm}   \Delta r(\Delta r + 2r) h $$

$$ V = \pi  \hspace{1mm} h ((\Delta r)^2 + 2r \Delta r) $$

The cylinder will be
$$V_{Cylinder} = \int_{0}^{R} \pi  \hspace{1mm} h ((\Delta r)^2 + 2r \Delta r)$$
$$V_{Cylinder} = \int_{0}^{R} \pi  \hspace{1mm} h ((d r)^2 + 2r dr)$$

Comment: To @kile: Can you describe the problem in more details?

Comment: @AntonVrdoljak Please see updated question

Comment: In the method of cylindrical shells the shell is thin enough that it is approximated by a rectangular cube whode dimensions are $(2\pi r)(h)(dr)$. You can visualize this by cutting the shell along the height of the cylinder and unrolling it. The method is justified in the limiting case.

Comment: @JohnDouma Can you tell me why $\pi h (dr)^2 $ is negelected?

Comment: It is insignificant. That is exactly how linear approximations work. If $dr\approx .01$ then $(dr)^2$ is about $.0001$. The difference between $dr$ and its square becomes even more pronounced as we make $dr$ smaller. Think about a regular integral under a function $f$. We ignore the gap between the rectangle and values of $f$ between $x$ and $x+dx$ for the same reason. As we take the limit as $dx$ or $dr$ goes to zero those gaps go away.

Comment: @JohnDouma How do I know when I should neglect stuff?

Comment: To @kile: thanx for more details. Next, I am confused with these part: "Volume of sphere" and $r$. Perhaps it is correct to use "Volume of cylindrical shell", and for $r$ that it is just an average of $r_1$ and $r_2$.

Comment: Take a simple function that you know how to integrate. Don't use a constant function because there will be no difference between the curve and the rectangles. Use a finite set of rectangles and compute the errors. Take progressively more rectangles to get a feel for it. This is a perfect exercise if you know how to program. Note that if you haven't studied the epsilon-delta form of limits, you may not be ready for this exercise.

Comment: @AntonVrdoljak You're right. But I just don't understand why we will choose $r$ is average of $r_1$ and $r_2$ instead of just $r_1$?

Comment: @kile There is a simpler exercise you can do with a calculator or a computer. Consider the function $f(x)=x^2+x$ Take large values of $x$ and compare $f(x)$ to $x^2$. Then take small values $<< 1$ of $x$ and compare $f(x)$ to $x$.

Comment: @JohnDouma I know how to program, but I don't understand your exercise.

Comment: Which one, the first or the second?

Comment: @JohnDouma  "Use a finite set of rectangles and compute the errors"

Comment: Take a function like $f(x)= x^2$ and compute the integral between two values like $1$ and $4$. Then compute the area under the curve by using rectangles whose width is some $\delta x$ and whose height is $f(x)$. For example you might have a rectangle whose width is from points $x=1$ to $x=1.1$ and whose height is $f(1)$. Fill these rectangles in for the entire interval and add their areas. How close is it to the integral? Now, instead of $0.1$, use widths of $.05$, then $.001$ and so forth and see how the sum of the areas of the rectangles compares to the integral.

Comment: You can do the same exercise with cylindrical shells using progressively thinner walls. How does the volume compare to the difference of the volumes of two cylinders as the walls become thinner?

Comment: To @kile: First, $r=\tfrac{r_1+r_2}{2}$ is both the midpoint of the interval $\left[r_1, r_2\right]$ and the average radius of the shell.
Second, see this material: https://www.csusm.edu/stemsc/handouts/calc_integration_cylindricalshells.pdf

Comment: A few thoughts: $1$. "Sphere" seems like a typo? $2$. Effectively, there is no impact of choosing $r = r_1$ versus $r = (r_1+r_2)/2$. They should lead to the right answer for the reasons that John Douma and Anton Vrdoljak have pointed out. Choosing the latter simply makes the limit calculation easier by eliminating the $(\Delta r)^2$ term. But it doesn't change the result; as John Douma says, that vanishes when we take the limit: If the whole cylinder's radius is $R$, that part becomes $n(\Delta r)^2 = \frac{R}{\Delta r}(\Delta r)^2 = R\Delta r \to 0$, where $n$ is the number of shells.

Comment: @AntonVrdoljak I think your link is broken

Comment: To @kile: It works as a charm for me. Let me try this (delete first h in the link): hhttps://www.csusm.edu/stemsc/handouts/calc_integration_cylindricalshells.pdf

Comment: @BrianTung I think your proof is flawed. Because you can also use $n (\Delta r)$, and you will get R. What's the point of using it? And where do you get this $n$?

Comment: @BrianTung My original only has $\pi h ((\Delta r) ^2 + 2 r \Delta r)$. I don't know where you get $n$

Comment: @kile: It's not a proof, it's just a sketch. My point is that the difference between your two expressions for $V$ is just $\pi h (\Delta r)^2$. If you take the Riemann sum (whose limit is the Riemann integral) with $n$ parts, which makes $\Delta r = R/n$, you get $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \pi h (\Delta r)^2 = n \pi h (\Delta r)^2 = R \pi h \Delta r$ (since $n = R/\Delta r$). If you take the limit as $\Delta r \to 0$, which is the Riemann integral, you get $0$, so the two expressions integrate to the same result.

Comment: For the other part, the part that both expressions have in common, which is $V = 2\pi h r \Delta r$, the Riemann sum is $2\pi h \sum_{k=1}^n r \Delta r$. But $r = (k-1)R/n$ and $\Delta r = R/n$ again, so we have $2\pi h \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(k-1)R^2}{n^2}$. But $\sum_{k=1}^n k-1 = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} k = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$. So our sum is now $2\pi h R^2 \frac{n(n-1)}{2n^2} = \pi h R^2 \left(1 - \frac1n\right) = \pi h R^2 \left(1 - \frac{\Delta r}{R}\right)$. In the limit as $\Delta r \to 0$, this is evidently just $\pi h R^2$, which is the right expression.

Comment: Note that taking the mean $(r_1+r_2)/2$ is essentially just using $r = (k-1/2)R/n$ instead of $r = (k-1)R/n$ in the comment immediately above. That difference goes away as $\Delta r \to 0$, just as we would expect. ¶ Incidentally, if the term "Riemann sum" doesn't mean anything to you, you might have to read up on that in order to understand the above explanation. Otherwise, you'll have to accept a hand-wavy explanation that the $(\Delta r)^2$ term diminishes "faster" (as the square) than $\Delta r$ does, as they both go to $0$, so it can be safely neglected.

Comment: @BrianTung Can you reformat your comment in the answer section? I really like your answer. This will very nice to someone who has similar question as I have to read.